# Replace each matching string with different value in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, string, replace

I have an input string and a pattern. I need to replace each match with a unique value. In C# I would do this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, e => GenerateNewString());
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ruby equivalent of `Regex.Replace` is `gsub`, which is an instance method on `String`. The rest is basically the same as in the C# version (except for the syntax of course):

```
input.gsub(pattern) { generate_new_string }
```

Comment: Wow, that's simple and it works! Could you explain what this means (gsub(...) is a method call but what happens in curly braces?)

Comment: @Konstantin: It's a block. Blocks are the most common way to pass anonymous functions in ruby.